# How to report standard deviations under mean values when using tbl_summary?

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary

I am using `gtsummary::tbl_summary` to create a summary statistics table. I am using the following codes to generate the table:

```
                         by = State, 
                         missing = "no",
                        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                        all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)")) %>%
                        modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>%
                        add_p() %>%                      
                        modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**States**") %>%
                        bold_labels()
```

The above code generates a table where standard deviations are reported within parenthesis next to the mean values. However, I would like the standard deviations to be reported underneath the mean values. How can I tweak my code to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this vignette example where summary stats are placed in different rows.
https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#continuous2

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg thanks. I already checked that out and tried adding ```type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2",``` inside ```tbl_summary```. But that didn't put standard deviations under mean values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check out the statistic argument. Rather than a string, pass a character vector with two elements

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Ok, got it! Thanks. This looks alright. But I would prefer not to have labels like "Mean" and "SD" printed out. But they get printed as default when I use ```continuous2```. Any other trick up the sleeve?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd like to see....